# Conversão de string JSON para objeto Java

Tags: java, android, json

Estou tentando converter uma string JSON em um objeto Java utilizado o Gson.

Esse aqui é o json que recebo do webservice:

```
{"concurso":
    {
        "numero":1499,
        "data_sorteio":"01\/06\/2013",
        "dezenas":[8,22,26,33,37,54]
    }
}
```

Aqui é minha classe pojo:

```
public class Concurso {

    private int numero;
    private String dataSorteio;
    private int[] dezenas;


    public Concurso() {
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {

        return numero + " - " + dataSorteio;
    }


}
```

Aqui é a forma como estou tentando converter a String Json em Java

```
Gson gson = new Gson();

Concurso concurso = gson.fromJson(stringJson, Concurso.class);

Log.v("teste", concurso.toString());
```

Aqui está a saida do LogCat

```
02-16 21:01:47.923  20796-20810/com.n3t0l0b0.blogspot.megasena.ativitys E/teste﹕ 0 - null
```

Não está dando erro em nada, só que a conversão da String Json para o objeto java simplesmente não ocorre, objeto fica nulo.

Comment: Acredito que vc precise criar os métodos get e set dos atributos.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Como quis mostrar o Marcio na outra resposta, o seu objeto "Concurso" está encapsulado, por isso você precisa extrai-lo. Se você estiver no comando da geração do json, pode simplesmente torná-lo mais simples dessa forma:

```
{
    "numero":1499,
    "data_sorteio":"01\/06\/2013",
    "dezenas":[8,22,26,33,37,54]
}
```

Caso contrário terá que utilizar uma classe de resposta.

```
public class ConcursoResponse {
    private Concurso concurso;

    public Concurso getConcurso() {
        return concurso;
    }
}
```

E ajustar o código para:

```
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    ConcursoResponse res = gson.fromJson(stringJson, ConcursoResponse.class);
    Log.v("MyApp", res.getConcurso().toString());
```

Mas isso não é o suficiente, seu POJO também precisa ser ajustado de forma a mapear o objeto **data_sorteio** para **dataSorteio** ficando assim:

```
public class Concurso {
    private int numero;
    @SerializedName("data_sorteio")
    private String dataSorteio;
    private int[] dezenas;

   @Override
    public String toString() {
        return numero + " - " + dataSorteio;
    }
}
```

O `@SerializedName` é o responsável por isso.

Comment: Eu não posso mexer no lado do webservice. Mas testei a solução proposta e funcionou perfeitamente. Muito obrigado!

Comment: @NetoLobo Legal! Só não esqueça de marcar a resposta como aceita.

Comment: Olá @NetoLobo, se a resposta funcionou, marque-a como solução! Ajuda a galera!

Comment: Onde sinalizo mesmo?

Comment: @NetoLobo bem abaixo da pontuação da resposta (atualmente em 7) no símbolo parecido com um "check"

Comment: Ah tah feito, Obrigado.

Answer (score 2):

Crie a classe:

```
public class Resposta {
  Concurso concurso;
  // getters & setters caso necessário
}
```

E altere seu código:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
Resposta res = gson.fromJson(stringJson, Resposta.class);
Concurso concurso = res.concurso;
Log.v("teste", concurso.toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

O [quick-json Parser](https://code.google.com/p/quick-json/) é muito simples, flexível, muito rápido e personalizável. Experimente

Características:

- Compatível
- com a especificação JSON (RFC4627)
- JSON parser de Alto Desempenho
- Apoia a abordagem de análise flexível / configurável
- Validação configurável de pares de chave / valor de qualquer JSON Hierarquia
- Fácil de usar # Muito Menos cópia do pé
- Aumenta desenvolvedor amigável e fácil de rastrear exceções
- Plugáveis ​​validação personalizada de apoio - chaves / valores podem ser validadas por meio da configuração validadores customizados, como e quando encontrou
- Validando e não-validação apoio parser
- O suporte para dois tipos de configuração (JSON / XML) para a utilização rápida json validar parser
- Requer JDK 1.5
- Sem dependência de bibliotecas externas
- Suporte para Json Geração através de serialização de objetos
- Supor te para o tipo de coleta de seleção durante o processo de análise

Ele pode ser usado assim:

```
JsonParserFactory factory=JsonParserFactory.getInstance();
JSONParser parser=factory.newJsonParser();
Map jsonMap=parser.parseJson(jsonString);
```