# converter json para objeto php

Tags: php, json

### UPDATE

Encontrei esta resposta do [**SOen**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9812059/5524514), no link sugerido pelo @Pedrox, fala sobre reflection, seria aplicavel a este caso também?

---

Conforme já me foi respondido aqui no [**SOpt**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/97415/converter-objeto-em-json-no-php), eu estava tentando converter uma lista de objetos para  json. Bom, agora eu preciso recuperar esta lista do json para um array de objetos.

O problema é que o `json_decode`, conforme diz a [**documentação**](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.json-decode.php), me retorna um array ora de um objeto especial chamado `stdObject` ou um array associativo, no meu caso este:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Corrente] => Array
                (
                    [tarifaManutencao] => 12.5
                    [numero] => 123
                    [proprietario] => teste
                    [saldo] => 3.1
                    [permissoesEspeciaisHabilitadas] => 
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [Poupanca] => Array
                (
                    [quantidadeConsultas] => 0
                    [numero] => 456
                    [proprietario] => testeprop
                    [saldo] => 50
                    [permissoesEspeciaisHabilitadas] => 
                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [Especial] => Array
                (
                    [limite] => 500
                    [valorEmprestado] => 0
                    [jurosCobrados] => 0
                    [tarifaManutencao] => 20
                    [numero] => 789
                    [proprietario] => teste4
                    [saldo] => 100
                    [permissoesEspeciaisHabilitadas] => 
                )

        )

)
```

O que eu precisava era retornar o array como lista de objetos, semelhante ao que as funções `serialize` e `unserialize` fazem.Vi [**neste tópico**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/6046/convers%C3%A3o-de-string-json-para-objeto-java) que no java tem como fazer isso, passando o `json` e a classe POJO do objeto customizado para um método da lib `Gson`, e ele converte automaticamente, e também que posso fazer isso usando um `foreach` ou `for`.

É possível eu recuperar meus objetos Corrente, Poupanca e Especial do json de forma semelhante ao java?

Comment: O problema que vc tem é não pode chamar os métodos `sacar()`, `depositar()`, `cobrarTarifa()` por exemplo?

Comment: @rray não entendi, como assim?

Comment: Por exemplo se vc fizer um foreach e dentro dele chamar o `sacar()` independente do tipo de conta, funciona? ou da erro?

Comment: @rray acredito que sim, pois no foreach eu teria que ficar dando `new` no objeto de acordo com o tipo e setando os atributos no construtor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Agradeço a todos pela contribuição, mas depois de estudar as sugestões e pesquisar sobre reflection, consegui criar um conversor de json para meus objetos, inclusive resolvendo o problema da herança de atributos, já que a `ReflectionClass` não traz propriedades herdadas diretamente. Ao invés de trabalhar com decode do `json` em forma de `array` associativo(`json_decode($file, true)`), preferi deixar como objetos `stdClass` por me facilitar tratar os atributos de forma mais generica.

Meu `json` decodificado ficou dessa forma agora:

```
array (size=3)
  0 => 
    object(stdClass)[3]
      public 'Especial' => 
        object(stdClass)[4]
          public 'limite' => int 500
          public 'valorEmprestado' => int 0
          public 'jurosCobrados' => int 0
          public 'tarifaManutencao' => int 20
          public 'numero' => int 789
          public 'proprietario' => string 'teste4' (length=6)
          public 'saldo' => int 100
          public 'permissoesEspeciaisHabilitadas' => boolean false
  1 => 
    object(stdClass)[5]
      public 'Poupanca' => 
        object(stdClass)[6]
          public 'quantidadeConsultas' => int 0
          public 'numero' => int 456
          public 'proprietario' => string 'testeprop' (length=9)
          public 'saldo' => int 50
          public 'permissoesEspeciaisHabilitadas' => boolean false
  2 => 
    object(stdClass)[7]
      public 'Corrente' => 
        object(stdClass)[8]
          public 'tarifaManutencao' => float 12.5
          public 'numero' => int 123
          public 'proprietario' => string 'teste' (length=5)
          public 'saldo' => float 3.1
          public 'permissoesEspeciaisHabilitadas' => boolean false
```

Em cada classe(Conta, Corrente e Poupanca, sendo essas duas ultimas herdando da primeira), está implementado a interface **[JsonSerializable](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/class.jsonserializable.php)** bem como seu método obrigatório, e nele eu crio um array contendo todos os atributos da classe(via `jsonSerialize()`) e, quando necessário, trago os métodos das classes ancestrais também, chamando o mesmo método(`parent::jsonSerialize()`).

No fim, minha classe ficou desta forma:

```
/**
 * Description of JSONToObject
 *
 * @author diego.felipe
 */
class JSONToObject {

    private $decodeJson;

    public function __construct($jsonFile) {
        if (file_exists($jsonFile)) {
            $strJson = file_get_contents($jsonFile);
            $this->decodeJson = json_decode($strJson);
            var_dump($this->decodeJson);
        }
    }

    public function getArrayObjects() {
        if (!is_null($this->decodeJson) && is_array($this->decodeJson)) {
            $lista = Array();
            foreach ($this->decodeJson as $stdClass) {
                $className = key($stdClass);
                $jsonObj = $stdClass->$className;
                $reflectionClass = new ReflectionClass($className);
                $instance = $reflectionClass->newInstanceWithoutConstructor();
                $allAttributes = Array();

                do {
                    $reflectionClassProperties = Array();
                    foreach ($reflectionClass->getProperties() as $classAttribute) {
                        $classAttribute->setAccessible(true);
                        $reflectionClassProperties[] = $classAttribute;
                    }
                    $allAttributes = array_merge($reflectionClassProperties, $allAttributes);
                } while ($reflectionClass = $reflectionClass->getParentClass());

                foreach ($allAttributes as $attribute) {
                    $attribute->setAccessible(true);
                    $attrName = $attribute->getName();
                    $attribute->setValue($instance, $jsonObj->$attrName);
                }
                $lista[] = $instance;
            }
            return $lista;
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Se eu entendi direito, você quer transformar a array gerada pelo json em object. Eu fazeria desta duas formas:

```
$json = (object) $json;
```

ou

```
foreach ($a as $key => $value) {
    $objeto->$key = $value;
}
```

Comment: Pensei nisso, porém, o array(ou json) guarda objetos diferentes, veja no código que postei. Corrente, Especial, Poupanca são objetos diferentes.

Comment: "fazeria" -> faria

Answer (score 1):

Dessa forma funciona:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/3243949/4566483

Na função "arrayToObject" no primeiro parametro vc passa o retorno do json_decode($string, true) e no segundo a string com o nome da classe para o qual vc precisa fazer o cast.

Segue o exemplo:

```
function arrayToObject(array $array, $className) {
    return unserialize(sprintf(
        'O:%d:"%s"%s',
        strlen($className),
        $className,
        strstr(serialize($array), ':')
    ));
}

class Pessoa {
  public $nome;
  public function __construct($nome) {
    $this->nome = $nome;
  }

  public function getNome(){
      return $this->nome;
  }
}

$jsonPessoa = '{"nome":"Fulano"}';

$objPessoa = arrayToObject(json_decode($jsonPessoa, true), "Pessoa");

var_dump($objPessoa->getNome());
```

Comment: Poderia colocar o código da função na sua resposta?

Comment: A conversão parece bem interessante, mas não entendi o que está sendo feito no código, se você ou alguém que saiba inglês puder traduzir parte da resposta, seria bacana.

Answer (score 0):

Tente algo como isso e me diz o que rolou?

```
function json_encode_private($object) {
    $public = [];
    $reflection = new ReflectionClass($object);
    foreach ($reflection->getProperties() as $property) {
        $property->setAccessible(true);
        $public[$property->getName()] = $property->getValue($object);
    }
    return json_encode($public);
}
```

Referência: [**SOen**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7005860/php-json-encode-class-private-members)
Documentação: [**PHP.Net**](http://us.php.net/manual/pt_BR/class.serializable.php)

Comment: O problema é que eu preciso retornar o json para meus objetos Poupanca, Corrente e Especial(tem um link de outra pergunta com as classes no texto). Porém, há heranças entre as classes e todas herdam de Conta, portanto, compartilham atributos.

Comment: Pelo que vi na outra questão, você está tentando gerar um json de atributos privados. Só que o uso do json é público. Para isso, use isso: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/class.jsonserializable.php

Comment: Ivan, a outra questão está resolvida justamente com o uso do jsonserializable, veja minha resposta la, só que o site só permite marcar minha resposta como a correta depois de 2 dias. Converter meus objetos para json eu consegui usando essa interface. Agora preciso fazer o inverso. Parece que é possivel fazer isso usando Reflection mas não conheço muito esse método.

Comment: veja se isso te ajuda: https://3v4l.org/vvv2g/bytecode

Comment: Vou tentar aqui no código.

Comment: Sinceramente nem consegui implementar essa classe nas minhas :/

Comment: Editei a pergunta, espero que tenha solucionado. Agora Usando Reflection. Como você havia comentado.

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda, mas na verdade eu preciso fazer o inverso, decode no json para objeto. Mas seu código já me deu uma base para fazer isso, vou tentar aqui.