# Como Pegar uma lista de json de uma Api em JAVA?

Tags: java, json, lista

Eu tenho o seguinte retorno de uma api `{"type":"champion","version":"7.10.1","data":{"89":{"id":89,"key":"Leona","name":"Leona","title":"a Alvorada Radiante"},"110":{"id":110,"key":"Varus","name":"Varus","title":"a Flecha da Vingança"}`

Estou começando agora a consumir mas não estou conseguindo. Pesquisei sobre [como pegar esse tipo de lista](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32624166/how-to-get-json-array-within-json-object)  mas ainda sim não estou conseguindo, é um pouco estranho porque tem uma array dentro da outra. Podem me dar um auxilio de como eu posso prosseguir?

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/6050/28595

Comment: Esse já é o retorno da API? Já fez a requisição e obteve isso de resultado?

Comment: Esse é o resultado já

Comment: Consegue adicionar a sua pergunta como tu faz a requisição?

Comment: @JeffersonSchmitt, para deixar aqui um pouco mais correto o sentido das palavras : um objeto json (como o que você mandou) é um mapeamento de chave valor. Uma lista é uma coleção de valores, como `['a', 'b', 'c']`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recomendo o uso da biblioteca chamada Jackson, é muito boa para fazer esse tipo de conversão em objetos java.

Se você usa maven, pode importar a seguinte biblioteca:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.0.pr3</version>
</dependency>
```

Caso não use, importe o seguinte jar na sua aplicação:

```
http://central.maven.org/maven2/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-databind/2.9.0.pr3/jackson-databind-2.9.0.pr3.jar
```

Segue uma exemplo funcional da leitura do json:

Crie uma classe chamada Champion com os seguintes dados:

```
import java.util.Map;

public class Champion {

    private String type;
    private String version;
    private Map<Integer, DadosChampion> data;

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public String getVersion() {
        return version;
    }

    public void setVersion(String version) {
        this.version = version;
    }

    public Map<Integer, DadosChampion> getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(Map<Integer, DadosChampion> data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Champion [type=" + type + ", version=" + version + ", data=" + data + "]";
    }
}
```

Crie outra classe chamada DadosChampion com os seguintes dados:

```
public class DadosChampion {

    private Integer id;
    private String key;
    private String name;
    private String title;

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getKey() {
        return key;
    }

    public void setKey(String key) {
        this.key = key;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }
}
```

Por fim, crie uma última classe chamada Principal com os seguintes dados:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Map;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

public class Principal {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonParseException, JsonMappingException, IOException {

        String json = "{\"type\":\"champion\",\"version\":\"7.10.1\",\"data\":{\"89\":{\"id\":89,\"key\":\"Leona\",\"name\":\"Leona\",\"title\":\"a Alvorada Radiante\"},\"110\":{\"id\":110,\"key\":\"Varus\",\"name\":\"Varus\",\"title\":\"a Flecha da Vingança\"}}}";

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        Champion champion = mapper.readValue(json, Champion.class);

        System.out.println("Tipo: " + champion.getType());
        System.out.println("Versão: " + champion.getVersion());

        System.out.println();

        System.out.println("Dados do champion:");
        System.out.println("---------------");

        for (DadosChampion dadosChampion : champion.getData().values()) {
            System.out.println("ID: " + dadosChampion.getId());
            System.out.println("KEY: " + dadosChampion.getKey());
            System.out.println("NOME: " + dadosChampion.getName());
            System.out.println("Title: " + dadosChampion.getTitle());
            System.out.println("---------------");
        }

        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("OUTRA FORMA DE PERCORRER: ");
        for (Map.Entry<Integer, DadosChampion> dadosChampion : champion.getData().entrySet()) {
            System.out.println("ID INDICE: " + dadosChampion.getKey());
            System.out.println("ID: " + dadosChampion.getValue().getId());
            System.out.println("KEY: " + dadosChampion.getValue().getKey());
            System.out.println("NOME: " + dadosChampion.getValue().getName());
            System.out.println("Title: " + dadosChampion.getValue().getTitle());
            System.out.println("---------------");
        }
    }

}
```

A saída sera o seguinte:

```
Tipo: champion
Versão: 7.10.1

Dados do champion:
---------------
ID: 89
KEY: Leona
NOME: Leona
Title: a Alvorada Radiante
---------------
ID: 110
KEY: Varus
NOME: Varus
Title: a Flecha da Vingança
---------------
```

Abraços.

Comment: Valeu mesmo diego , funcionou certinho , uma unica observação é que  tive que baixar o jacksonall porque deu  esse erro: 
"error: cannot access JsonProcessingException"
pesquisando no stack gringo explicou  o pessoal que teve esse mesmo erro usou o all e funcionou , comigo também então vou deixar o link aqui também http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/j/Downloadjacksonall199jar.htm

Comment: @JeffersonSchmitt Certo.. obrigado pelo feedback, alterei o link para esse  jar.

Uma observação, caso vc queira alterar o nome dos seus atributo da classe java, vc pode. Basta apenas colocar a propridade @JsonProperty("label") acima do seu atributos e especificar qual propriedade do json ela se refere.

Mais detalhes em https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-docs

Att

Comment: Uma duvida o que seria esse toString() ?,  Caso eu queria fazer com outro json que tenha mais um desse mesmo tipo data por exemplo um tipo tem o "type":,"version": , depois tem uma lista chamada "basic:{...}" e depois o "data:{...}" eu adicionaria mais um map? como eu poderia fazer ?

Comment: O toString retorna uma representação do objeto em forma de String. Se vc executar o método toString ele não vai mostrar a referência do objeto e sim o conteúdo dele em forma de String.

Depende da estrutura do json, vc criaria uma classe Basic e dentro dela criaria o data. Se vai ser um Map ou não depende da estrutura do json.

Depois vc cria um objeto da classe Basic dentro da classae Champion.

Se tiver um exemplo do json que vc está em dúvida coloca aqui que te mostro com exemplos.

Comment: Fiz um pastebin exemplificando pastebin.com/wSrwMkGV tem vários um dentro do outro, como ficaria ? Exemplo eu tenho ali um "basic" depois  o image , stats ,gold,rune e por ultimo o data, eu precisaria fazer um map de todos eles ? sendo que eu preciso apenas do data. como posso fazer ?

Comment: @JeffersonSchmitt Acima da declaração da classe vc pode adicionar a propriedade @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true) que ela vai ignorar os campos que não estão na sua classe e estão no json.

Classe Item:
https://pastebin.com/BXXXqN9K

Classe DadosItem:
https://pastebin.com/wwxPujLB

Classe Principal:
https://pastebin.com/FwYZDH5H

Vai ser necessário atualizar os imports das classes.

Comment: Eu tinha comentado sobre o @jsonignore mas não enviou para cá mas essas outras propriedades eu não tinha feito , funcionou tudo tranquilo , valeu mesmo pela ajuda , eu não teria conseguido sem essa força. Abraços

Comment: @JeffersonSchmitt
As outras propriedades não são obrigatórias, mas com elas vc consegue colocar o nome que quiser no atributo da sua classe e mapear qual valor do json seu atributo ira pegar.