# como receber / imprimir o conteudo em json de uma API

Tags: java, json, api

OLA, sou novo na area de API e estou consumindo uma API de previsão do tempo.
consegui "conectar" na api, recebi o resultado 200 ok mas agora quero saber como receber os dados em json da api.
eu sei que para receber os dados do endpoint tenho que passar os parametros de cidade e país. (desculpa se usei termos que não fazem sentido).

```
URL url = new URL("https://reqbin.com/echo");
         HttpURLConnection http = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
         http.setRequestProperty("Accept", "*/*");       
         http.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Bearer 9c40e8ea24eaabf937f16e0fbb7ff186");
         System.out.println(http.getResponseCode() + " " + http.getResponseMessage());       
                 
         String contentType = http.getContentType();
         System.out.println(contentType);
                 
                 
         http.disconnect();
```

Comment: Isto responde à sua pergunta? [Conversão de string JSON para objeto Java](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/6046/convers%c3%a3o-de-string-json-para-objeto-java)

Comment: na vdd não haha :(

Comment: O que você quer tirar de dúvida, especificamente?

Answer (score 0):

Junior, também sou iniciante, mas assim como capturou o contentType, você pode pegar o body retornado pela API.
Eu usei o `java.net.http` e a API da IMDB, ficou assim:

```
 URI apiIMDB = URI.create("https://imdb-api.com/en/API/Top250Movies/" + apiKey);

    HttpClient client = HttpClient.newHttpClient();
    HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.newBuilder().uri(apiIMDB).build();

    HttpResponse<String> response = client.send(request, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString());
    String json = response.body();
```

Pronto o JSON está ai na váriavel como uma String.
Essa é uma forma de fazer direto sem recursos externos, ja que o `java.net.http` esta incluso no java 11+

Pode usar as bibliotecas Jackson e Gson também. São bem famosas e bem tem muito conteúdo espalhado pela rede!

Comment: salve man, entao mas ai o problema ainda é o mesmo, por exemplo eu queria 
 retornar apenas a temperatura, ou a velocidade do vento, não queria ver toda a lista json